# Spring Security custom filter chain proxy using java config for mvc application

Tags: spring, security, spring-boot

We are trying to use Spring Security in a Spring Boot application and would like to use the java config to configure spring security. 
On top of this we would like to use our own filters to modify some behaviour before and after logging in. 
Something similar to http://sleeplessinslc.blogspot.in/2012/02/spring-security-stateless-cookie-based.html

Does anyone have any idea how to create the SecurityConfig.java where we can customize the filter sequence and add our own filters to it.

Have tried http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2014/07/spring-security-custom-filterchainproxy.html but didn't get it to point to the my login page.

Comment: are you use spring boot for rest service purpose?

Answer (score 2):

You can add CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilterto the securityCOnfig.java

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 @Bean
public CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter()
        throws Exception {


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("USER").and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll();
    http.addFilterBefore(new CustomFilter(), LogoutFilter.class);
    //.and().anonymous().disable();
}
```

Here is a similar post - [Spring security custom authentication filter without web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784652/spring-security-custom-authentication-filter-without-web-xml)

Here are two tutorials - http://www.journaldev.com/2715/spring-security-in-servlet-web-application-using-dao-jdbc-in-memory-authentication

Comment: Hi Paul, 

Thanks for the reply.
What I want to do is basically create a stateless application and not use the default (persistent) JSESSIONID at all. I want to use a encrypted token as a cookie and use that as an authentication strategy for users already logged in.
I was able to create my own AuthSucessHandler and added a filter before UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. What I now need is a mechanism to bypass the authentication when my custom filter finds a valid cookie. Would really appreciate some more insight..